# Onboard does not send keys to the MATE login screen?

Tags: 14.04, login, mate

I have installed MATE desktop on Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit, and it also installed its own greeter, which I prefer:

[image: mate-lightdm-greeter.png]

I believe this is the lightdm greeter (`lightdm-gtk-greeter`?), but I'm not sure.

Anyways, this laptop has a touchscreen, and so I enabled onboard to start with the login screen (full disclosure - the screenshot process couldn't capture it, so I've pasted it in additionally on the above screenshot).

So this is all good - but when I come to the login screen, and try to type in my password via the touchscreen - I can see `onboard`'s buttons light up when pressed (so the sensor in itself is not a problem) - but no keys are propagated to the login passsword field, even if I make efforts to select it so it is focused (and unlike on the screenshot, usually I have a text pointer in that field, indicating it is focused/selected).

BTW, same problem if I use the mouse to press the `onboard` keys.

So what can I do, so as to be able to login via touchscreen through this greeter? I suspect I may be missing some package, but I'm not sure...

Comment: That does not look like LightDM to me.  It might be GDM, but I could be wrong, it looks a bit different than the GDM sign-in that I have in Gnome.    Can't offer any help with your issue but if you try searching using GDM or Gnome it might help you find a resolution.

Comment: Thanks @TrailRider - good to know I'm probably mistaken in identifying the greeter...